# Finding duplicate Substrings?

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring, formula

Is there a logical way to find duplicate substrings in a string that would work regardless of how many times the substring is duplicated; then return the amount of times it was duplicated with the final word.

```
For example, abc-abc-abc-
Can be broken into | abc- | abc- | abc-
                                 = abc- x3

Example 2, abc-abc-abc-abc-
Can be broken into | abc- | abc- | abc- | abc-
                                        = abc- x4
```

For even repetitions, it is not a problem to split the string in half and then compare both substrings. Then you can keep looping until the halves do not match.

For odd string length, you can break it into 3rds and compare all three parts and do the same thing.

The problem happens when a word repeats 7 or 11 times. Dividing the length by 4 or 5 could work.

So for example, a string with `yesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesno` has the substring `yesno` repeating `7 times.`

Is there some sort of a formula, regex, or linq that can transform `yesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesno` to `yesno (x7)`?

Comment: You want the longest repeating substring ? Can there be other strings between substring ? Like aaaaaabaaaaaa (x2 aaaaaa)?

Comment: If you want the longest repeating substring, then `abc-abc-abc-abc-` would be represented as `abc-abc- x2`

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I asked about the `shortest` substring. So that can be broken down further into `abc-`

Comment: @brz That is considered a unique string. Now if it were `aaaaaabaaaaaab`, then it would be `aaaaaab` repeating x2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this worked for me `(..*?)(?=\1(?=\1*$)|$)` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gX3fX0/2)
or even shorter `(..*?)(?=\1*$)` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gX3fX0/3)

- `(..*?)` capture at least one character and add as many as needed
- `(?=\1*$)` lookahead for the previously captured results as many times as possible to the end.

Comment: This looks great and finds same words, but it doesn't see `yesnoyesnoyesnoyesno1` as a unique string. `yesno1` is counted as a duplicate.

Comment: Excellent regex. Would be helpful for others if you could explain the regex breakdown.

Comment: Why not .+ instead of ..*? ?

Comment: `.+` will gobble the whole string, you could use `.+?` though

Answer (score 1):

```
var list=new string[]{"abc-abc-abc-",
                    "abc-abc-abc-abc-",
                    "yesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesnoyesno"};
var reg=new Regex("(.+?)(?=\\1|$)");
foreach(var str in list)
{
  string result=string.Format("{0} (x{1})",reg.Match(str).Value,  reg.Matches(str).Count);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
abc- (x3)
abc- (x4)
yesno (x7)
```

Comment: This is very close, but is there a way to count a string as non repeating if it can't be broken down perfectly? Such as `1231231234` is counted as `123 (x3)` but needs to be left as a unique string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's very helpful. alpha bravo's regex plugged into your code would be the prefect answer.